# istream_iterator invalid when using std::copy

Tags: c++, iterator, copy, stdin

I'm trying to copy some `ints` from `stdin` into a `vector`. I have the code working but I'm unsure why I need the `()` after the second argument of `copy`. By this I mean the `istream_iterator<int>()` argument in the `copy` call.

Code here...

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::copy;
using std::cin;
using std::istream_iterator;

int main()
{   
     vector<int> nums;
     copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(nums)); // why do I need the empty brackets after the 2nd argument?

     return 0;
}
```

If I remove the brackets I get an error from the compiler, however if I slightly modify my code to code below my program works fine.

```
int main()
{   
     vector<int> nums;
     istream_iterator<int> end; // no brackets used here
     copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), end, back_inserter(nums)); 

     return 0;
}
```

I'm coming from a Java background so empty brackets simply means you have used an empty constructor. The first code snippet goes against what I thought I understood, from my understanding in C++ if you  want to use an empty constructor you simply miss off the `()` however this isn't the case here

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the code working but I'm unsure why I need the `()` after the second argument of copy

You need them to construct an iterator in place, instead of declaring a separate variable representing one-past-the-end of an input stream. If you write

```
istream_iterator<int>
```

without parentheses, that would be a type name. With parentheses that's an invocation of a default constructor:

```
istream_iterator<int>()
```

An `istream_iterator<int>` object is constructed in place, and passed to `std::copy` as its second argument. By convention, the default constructor of `istream_iterator<T>` gives you an instance of the iterator that signals one-past-the-end of a stream.

Comment: So if I have a `vector<int> nums;` does that mean I have a type name but haven't called a constructor?

Comment: @CSStudent No, it does not, because you would use `vector<int>` in a context of a declaration, as opposed to the context of a function call.  `vector<int> nums` is a declaration, while `copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>, back_inserter(nums))` is a function invocation.

Comment: @CSStudent  Using a type to declare a variable implies a call of default constructor. Using a type as a function parameter does not imply anything, because it is semantically illegal.

Comment: Right I see your point. To me it seems strange that you miss off the `()` depending where you are planning to use the object (coming from Java)

Comment: @CSStudent This is because Java is more explicit than C++: when you write `ArrayList<Integer> x` Java does not initialize `x` at all, requiring you to write `new ArrayList<Integer>()`. C++ lets you skip the `new`, the type, and the parentheses. It also lets you drop `new` when you are making a function call, shortening things a little (at the expense of making them less readable, at least to my taste).

Comment: @CSStudent Some people use a style called [AAA](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) where you would write it as `auto end = istream_iterator<int>()`

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>, back_inserter(nums));
```

is meaningless.  `istream_iterator<int>` is a type not an object.  You need to use `()` to create an unnamed, temporary, default-constructed object of the type `istream_iterator<int>`.

Using

```
istream_iterator<int> end;
```

You declare an object of the type `istream_iterator<int>`, and you do not need the parentheses, as it is default-constructed without them.  In fact, if you had used parentheses, like:

```
istream_iterator<int> end();
```

Then you would have run into a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue and `end` would now be a function taking nothing and returning a `istream_iterator<int>`.

Comment: Why isn't the no bracket version in the `copy` call default constructed for me?

Comment: @CSStudent Because you are not creating a variable.  You just named a type. `istream_iterator<int> end;` says make a variable name `end`of the type `istream_iterator<int>`.  `istream_iterator<int>` is just a type

Answer (score 1):

It might be confusing but both cases creating an object by default constructor. And for the 1st case you must use `()`, for the 2nd case you must not use `()`.

`istream_iterator<int>()` creates a temporary object by default constructor. Without `()`, `istream_iterator<int>` is just a type name, which doesn't make sense because an instance of the type expected.

`istream_iterator<int> end;` creates a named object by default constructor too. You can't use `()` here, otherwise it will become a declaration of function, which takes no parameter and returns `istream_iterator<int>`. See [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense as to why you don't include the `()` when declaring an object.

Comment: @CSStudent So for the 1st case you must use, for the 2nd case you must not use `()`. Hope the explanations in answer helps you to distinguish them.